How resize png inside button in MAUI?
What I expect:
Button with size 58x38 and an icon in it with size 14x14.
What I try:
1)
<Button 
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource cBlue6}"  
        WidthRequest="58"
        HeightRequest="38"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        ImageSource="error.png"
        >
</Button>

But I don't know how can I resize error.png.
2)
<ImageButton 
    Source="error.png"
    WidthRequest="58"
    HeightRequest="38"
/>

Here entire button is an icon but I want to icon only size 14x14.
I am looking for something like:
<Button 
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource cBlue6}"  
        WidthRequest="58"
        HeightRequest="38"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        >
    <Image Source="error.png" HeightRequest="14" WidthRequest="14"/>
</Button>

But I can't nested anything into Button. There is an error "The type 'Button' does not support direct content".

You can do something similar to what I said in one of the recent maui discussions https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/21381
That is:
Implement a markup extension which has an aim to provide a FontImageSource.
Create properties for color, size and glyph documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.fontimagesource?view=net-maui-8.0
Now using these properties create a FontImageSource and return it.
Now just call this in your xaml for your button
ImageSource="{local:iconextension glyph="...", color="...",size="..."}"

What if my icon should size 20x14? The size is double type but I need set width and height.

Another question is how can I attach image source to "error.png"?

@infinitesimal using the extension which has a glyph property where u can provide the string value of the file. I doubt you can do 20x14 using built in functionality. So just one size should do it. It might be as close as you can go without external dependency

This option is not available in the .NET MAUI button you could use the custom button I have created if you are interested:
Checkout: https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls
And then add the image in the leading or trailing space with the size you would like
  <freakyControls:FreakyButton
        Animation="FadeAndScale"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
        BorderColor="Black"
        BusyColor="White"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap"
        Text="Edged icon trailing with fade and scale"
        TextColor="White"
        IconSize="58"
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
        <freakyControls:FreakyButton.TrailingIcon>
            <Image Source="calendar.png" HeightRequest="58" WidthRequest ="38"  />
        </freakyControls:FreakyButton.TrailingIcon>
 </freakyControls:FreakyButton>

